# Matrix transpose similarity with regards to complex and real number field

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the question with following problem:

Prove that every complex $n \times n$ matrix is similar to its own transpose.

---

My thoughts is to manipulate a matrix and its transpose to show that their Jordan forms are the same. i.e. through showing that $N(A - \lambda I) = N(A^T - \lambda I),\space N((A - \lambda I)^2) = N((A^T - \lambda I)^2), ...$.

But I fail to see how the complex field matters. i.e. what would happen to a $\mathbb{R}$ entried matrix if its eigenvalues are complex and how it would affect its similarity with its transpose.

Comment: Doesn't $\det((A-\lambda I))^k) =\det((A^\top-\lambda I))^k)$ show that $J = P^{-1}A P = Q^{-1} A^\top Q$ ?